# Start sort at specified charachter

Tags: php, mysql

I am grabbing information from the DB for a form select list. I want the default for the form to be Orange. The form select options are grabbed from the database that is updated by the user ('Colors'). So orange is the only color that starts with 'O' so I figure there has to be a way to start the sort order with a certain char (in this case O).

Here is what I have that grabs the colors column from the DB and puts the rows into a form option select.

```
$color_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM color");
/* Some stuff here */
echo '<select name="Color" id="color">'; 
while ($row_item = mysql_fetch_array($color_select)){ 
$pname = $row_item["color"]; 
echo "<OPTION value=\"$pname\">$pname</OPTION>"; 
} 
echo '</SELECT>'; 
/* Some stuff here */
```

Comment: why you dont sort with `PHP` instead of `MySQL`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth Thanks, I am new to php mysql and have been using tutorials to get me through (most of them are old so they use the mysql_* Function. I will be sure to stop using this and start using PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by i combination med if är trevligt

```
ORDER BY IF(color = 'orange', 0, 1), color;
```

Har du därimot flera specialfall är case användbar:

```
ORDER BY CASE color WHEN 'Orange' THEN 0 WHEN 'Red' 1 WHNE 'Green' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, color;
```